# Поддомен к сайту

Tags: php

Здравствуйте. Есть сайт site.ru и поддомен sub.site.ru, нужно что бы при заходе через поддомен отображался сайт site.ru и на нём было написано, через какой поддомен зашёл человек. То есть в данном случае: "Вы зашли через поддомен sub". Но не могу разобраться чтобы открывался главный сайт через переход по поддомену.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотрим на ответ [@Gedweb](/users/10995/gedweb) и в алисах сайта ставим `*` таким образом сайт будет доступен по какому угодно поддомену.

Далее к примеру такой скрипт:

```
$site_url = 'site.com';

if($site_url != $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])
{
    $subdomain = preg_replace('/(.*).'.$site_url.'/', '$1', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);

    echo 'Вы зашли через поддомен ', $subdomain;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

php тут не причём, это [настройка сервера](http://westseo.ru/mod-rewrite-subdomain/)

Answer (score -1):

в sub.site.ru нужна только одна строчка

# index.php

```
header('Location: http://site.ru/');
```

а с какого поддомена зашли на site.ru можно узнать с помощью:

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']
```

Comment: ... это если браузер или антивирус не режет referrer.

Comment: вот так и хочется вам влепить минус, а как клиент попадёт на скрипт с указанным вами кодом? Поделитесь сакральным знанием

Comment: скрипт, я так понимаю, дефолтный

Comment: Если вы не знаете о чём говорите, лучше пройдите мимо. Не нужно ни кого вводить в заблуждение, и себя кстати тоже...

----------

вы предлагаете создавать over9000 поддоменов с редиректами, это в корне неверный подход

Comment: так мне тоже нужно тогда разобраться! сообщество поправит. что я не так говорю?

Comment: Нужно чтобы всегда пользователь находился на поддомене с которого пришёл.

Comment: ну.. меня сбило "Но не могу разобраться чтобы открывался главный сайт через переход по поддомену.". да, наверное я неправ.